# Selecting certain columns based on their value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a spreadsheet of all my inquiries.

I want to select all the columns for example with "B". My main aim is to see as a quick summery, all the people who have booked.
Then if I wanted to see all my inquiries I can select just the "E" columns and it will then hide all my cancellations and bookings.

[image: inquiries list]

Comment: Honestly I'm unable to understand the issue, please [Edit] your post & be specific all about you need.

Comment: Furthermore, why would you want to be able to select column `P` and `R`? What's the end goal here, as selecting ranges is poor practice within Excel.

Comment: Can you describe it more clearly?

Comment: Select one column you need (click on sheet's column header, `'P'`). Then tap Ctrl and select another column(s).

Comment: my main aim is to see just the people that have booked (B).  Or just my enquiries (E) or just my cancellations (C)  so that i can see in a more clear view.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wish to hide all columns whose first cell does not contain "E"
or "B".
This requires a VBA macro.

First step is to save the spreadsheet as `.xlsm` to allow VBA macros,
then open it using Excel.

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor.
Right-click either "Sheetl (Sheetl)" or "ThisWorkbook" and select
*Insert > Module*.

Copy-paste the following text inside the editor:

```
Sub Hide_Columns_Not_A()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:E1").Cells
    If c.Value <> "A" Then
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c
End Sub

Sub Hide_Columns_Not_E()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:E1").Cells
    If c.Value <> "E" Then
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c
End Sub

Sub Unhide_All_Columns()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:E1").Cells
    c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Next c
End Sub
```

**Important**: Change in the above text all three occurrences of `A1:E1`
to the real range, which in your case seems to be at least `A1:U1`.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the spreadsheet, and then
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close the VBA editor and return to Excel.

You may from now on go to the *Developer* pane, click on *Macros* which
will display the three defined macros, select the one you want and click
*Run*.

[image]